# Алгоритм спектрального шумоподавления

Tags: алгоритм, аудио

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм *спектрального шумоподавления* в аудио.

Я в этом деле не особо смыслю. В сети информации не нашёл.
Так понимаю, самым главным в алгоритме является процесс вычисления шума в сигнале. Причём весь шум полностью убрать невозможно, ввиду его разного характера.

В известных мне программах по работе со звуком, при использовании спектрального шумоподавления создаётся сначала "профиль" шума, а потом он удаляется из обрабатываемой записи.

Таким образом, понять не могу, нужно самостоятельно искать шум или заранее заготовить примеры шумов? Дальше, ну вот имею я этот чистый шум - как он "вычитается" из целой записи (оперировать прошу массивом байт представляющих аудиозапись в 2 каналах)?

**P.S.** Не нужно давать ссылки на книги по работе со звуком. Я прикладной разработчик и углубляться в эту тему не хочу, а готовых реализаций не существует...

---

Ответ @bukkojot содержит описание результативного (как он убеждает) алгоритма спектрального вычитания, однако, требуются пояснения, которые автор давать отказывается. В чём я бы хотел разобраться/что мне не понятно:

- Что значит "нарезать оригинал сигнал на окошки"? О каких окнах идёт речь? Одним поисковым запросом можно осознать факт существования оконных функций, которые предназначены для борьбы с растеканием спектра. Но речь идёт, как мне кажется всё таки не об этом.
- "Чтобы не возникло спектральной утечки, окошки перемножаем, к примеру, на окно Блекмана-Харриса" - Что из себя представляет окно Блекмана-Харриса? Какой то массив чисел определённой длины? С какими данными производится это действие? С окошками, на который нарезан исходный сигнал, или всё таки с его спектром, полученным через БФП?
- "Бежим по спектру смотрим, а не больше ли оно того, что у нас в слепке шума" - Что *ОНО*?
- "Слегка сглаживаем нашу найденную карту" - Что есть *карта*?
- "глушим в обе стороны от найденных позиций" - Уменьшаем пару соседних значений? На сколько?
- "Выбрасываем результат в окошко и нормализуем" - В какое окошко? Что означает нормализация?
- Что даёт БФП на выходе? Массив комплексных чисел, представляющих спектр сигнала. Это ясно. Вычисляется ряд Фурье. Но, по идее же, спектр выглядит как сопоставление частоты сигнала по оси абсцисс со значением амплитуды по оси ординат. А у меня просто, так понимаю, массив из амплитуд входящих сигналов. И как понять какая амплитуда какой частоте составляющей соответствует?
- Можно ли удалять сразу несколько шумов или нужно иметь только одну какую-то запись?

Ответы на эти вопросы **полностью решаю мою проблему** :)

Comment: > хочу просто разобраться с один вот этим алгоритмом

Comment: Не смутило, а?.

Comment: Ну, например, нажимаешь на педали кнопку LEARN, при этом ничего не говоришь в микрофон или прижимаешь струны у гитары и нажимаешь ту же кнопку. Потом отпускаешь кнопку и дальше играешь и поешь. Вот примеры, как берутся образцы шума. Или детектируешь в сигнале фрагменты с низкой амплитудой, проверяешь их спектр - если шумоподобный - тоже берешь как образец шума.

Comment: Не, как заготовить образы шума, у меня нет вопроса. Только что, если идти таким путём, насколько много надо готовить образов и применять ли все сразу?

Comment: Готовые алгоритмы. Если просто вычесть амплитуду из Фурье-образа сигнала, то при использовании НПФ (непрерывное преобразование Фурье) - все нормально, но очень медленно, а вот БПФ работает с блоками, на границах которых будут щелчки. Куда их девать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Переформулированного? Я ничего не менял. Просто жирным выделил то, что вы видимо не прочли...

Comment: @AlexanderZonov "Если просто вычесть амплитуду из Фурье-образа сигнала" - это вы о чём? О вычитании?

Comment: Расскажите, вы, кажется, знаете, а как это вычитание делается и при чём тут преобразование Фурье?

Comment: Из абсолютных значений комплексных чисел вычесть абсолютные значения других комплексных чисел.

Comment: Логично. Так а что это за комплексные числа? То, что представляет сэмпл?

Comment: @DStark это фурье-образ сигнала. Блок исходного сигнала, подвергнутый преобразованию Фурье. Хотя бы это надо знать, чтобы изучать что-то о >спектральном шумоподавлении. Я же не буду вам лекции по матану читать.

Comment: @D.Stark, было "с один", стало "с одиним")

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Окей, понял. bukkojot предлагает заюзать окна Блекмана-Харриса для сглаживания сигнала. Что это за вещь?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Отредактировал вопрос. Возможно, вы могли бы дать удовлетворительный ответ)

Comment: Восемь-в-одном вопросов! Конкурс неслыханной щедрости: аж целых 50 баллов!

Comment: Дак в смысле? Это чтобы вопрос в конкурсные вывести. Вы так говорите, как будто какие там баллы вас волнуют больше самого вопроса. Не забывайте, что суть этого форума - это создать базу знаний программистов, решая различные вопросы, а не накопить какие то там баллы, которые ничего по себе не значат (как в компьютерной игре). И как раз такого вопроса как мой в этой базе знаний нет (и даже подобных).

Comment: Да и вопросов у меня, по сути, не 8, а один. Просто я указал, чем стоит дополнить имеющийся ответ. Для знающего человека это просто "пара слов" по каждому пункту...

Comment: Вообщем, отвечайте по теме, пожалуйста.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov А как делается удаления шума методом гейта? Удаляются частоты определённые так понимаю. После БФП я получаю массив амплитуд? Как узнать какая амплитуда какой частоте соответствует?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Ну в смысле, имеем некоторый алгоритм БФП: https://ru.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Реализации_алгоритмов/Быстрое_преобразование_Фурье. Возвращается массив структур типа [`Complex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx). Как имея эти данные построить спектр (частота-амплитуда)?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он противоречит правилам сайта: в вопросе должен быть только один вопрос.

Comment: Ну это как бы комментарии к существующему ответу. Просто автор не отвечает (намеренно) - вот я и подумал, могут ли другие пользователи ответить исходя из данных пояснений)

Answer (score 12):

> Не нужно давать ссылки на длиннющие статьи с серьёзной матчастью и
>   книги по работе со звуком!

Окей, мы их тут перескажем в кратком изложении, как это принято в современном образовании.

Для начала нам нужен семпл шума, ну или того, что вы считаете шумом. Шумом может быть наводка электросети, помехи передачи или кривые драйвера. Или все вместе взятое.

Так как у нас спектральное шумоподавление, то из всего этого лучше получить спектр, пропустив наш шум через БПФ. Мы получаем слепок того, что нам в общем-то не нужно. Так как шума обычно много, слепок нам нужен небольшой, то лучше всего эти частоты как-то усреднить, используя множество окошек, на которые мы нарезали оригинальный сигнал.

Далее режем наш оригинальный сигнал на окошки. Чтобы не возникло спектральной утечки, окошки перемножаем, к примеру, на [окно Блекмана-Харриса](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Blackman.E2.80.93Harris_window) (ну, это мое субъективное предпочтение) или что-то подобное. И после этого, раскладываем на спектр и удаляем шум.

Удаление шума, фактически, совсем простое:

1. Бежим по спектру смотрим, а не больше ли оно того, что у нас в слепке шума? И если так, то запоминаем где и что
2. Слегка сглаживаем нашу найденную карту
3. Слегка глушим в обе стороны от найденных позиций
4. Делаем обратное преобразование Фурье
5. Выбрасываем результат в окошко и нормализуем

Текст выше написан глядя на исходники отличного шумодава от Доминика Маззони и алгоритм доказал свою работоспособность временем.

Могу посоветовать отсмотреть цикл лекций по спектральному разложению (у Принстона отличный курс на ютубе и относительно короткий - примерно 40 лекций по часу).

Comment: Ну почему же не поможет... Давайте поясним некоторые вещи. Тут не хватает определения окна, карты и нормализации. Дополните ответ этими пояснениями, и у меня не останется вопросов)

Comment: С нормализацией у нас в прошлый раз плохо все вышло. Мы сошлись на том, что я тролль и меня надо игнорировать. Что ты и обещал делать.

Comment: Ну во-первых, вас троллем назвал админ, а во-вторых, наша предыдущая дискуссия не относилась к теме вопроса, о чём я не переставал напоминать каждым комментарием. Сейчас я имею вполне более конкретный вопрос и вижу, в отличии от предыдущего раза, ваш адекватный ответ. Я лишь хочу уточнить пару вопросов ещё у знающего человека.

Comment: Не понятно главное вот про окна.

Comment: Пока что, так понимаю, это позволяет улучшить сигнал добавлением боковых лепестков к значениям в спектре. Существует несколько алгоритмов для этого, и вы мне предлагаете один конкретный (его и буду использовать).

Comment: "Шумом может быть наводка электросети, помехи передачи или кривые драйвера. Или все вместе взятое." - можно несколько слепков шума использовать что-ли? Или совместить все шумы в одном сигнале, я не понял.

Comment: Так что за окошки на которые мы должны нарезать оригинальный сигнал не ясно...

Answer (score 5):

Готовых реализаций не существует по той же причине почему нет какого-то эталона шума, который можно было бы смело удалять из всех записей. Шум везде разный, значит для каждого вида шума свой алгоритм. Или хотя бы свои настройки для более-менее универсального алгоритма.

Получается следующий алгоритм:

1. Устанавливаете Audacity.
2. Для вашего образца находите оптимальные, то есть удаляющие максимум шума, [настройки для фильтра шумоподавления](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/noise_reduction.html).
3. Настройки записываете.
4. [Берёте исходники фильтра.](https://github.com/audacity/audacity/blob/master/src/effects/NoiseRemoval.cpp)
5. Удаляете из исходников фильтра всё, имеющее отношение к GUI.
6. Подставляете ранее сохранённые настройки фильтра прямо в коде.
7. На вход программно подаёте ваш образец.
8. На выходе получаете образец без шума.

Если нужно реализовать эту последовательность шагов для вас в виде готового кода для вашей программы для вашего образца, задайте отдельный вопрос с конкретным примером. Такой вопрос скорее всего закроют, так как делать за вас домашнюю работу - это оффтопик, но задать вы всё равно его можете.