# Быстрое преобразование Фурье и обратное преобразование

Tags: c#, фурье

Я ищу реализацию БПФ на .NET-совместных языках.
Однако, то множество реализаций, что мне удалось найти возвращают массив комплексных чисел - значений амплитуд. Мне нужно получить сопоставление частот и амплитуд (т.е. спектр). Например, вот готовые примеры БПФ на wiki: [Быстрое преобразование Фурье](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5).

Возможно, для получения нужного результата достаточно знать ширину окна, по которому рассчитывается БПФ.

Ну, говоря об обратном преобразовании, готовых реализаций вообще не нашёл.

Comment: Ну вообще-то быстрое и обратное это по сути одно и тоже преобразование. http://e-maxx.ru/algo/fft_multiply Рекомендую изучить.

Comment: В предыдущем моём вопросе мне объяснили, что это разные вещи) Хм. Может я просто не верно выразился? Мне нужно получить спектр сигнала как сопоставление частот и значений амплитуд, выполнить с этими значениями свои действия (например, удалить какие-то частоты) и после всего получить изменённый сигнал исходной длины. Для первого шага, думал, подойдёт БПФ, а для третьего (последнего) - обратное преобразование Фурье. А как тогда, если не так?

Comment: Есть прямое и обратное преобразование. Оба выполняются по алгоритму БПФ. И, вообще говоря, "подкорректировать частоты" - так делать нельзя. Все, что можно делать с Фурье-образом хорошим девочкам - это умножать и преобразовывать назад в сигнал. БПФ - инструмент для быстрого вычисления сверток, то есть применения к сигналу цифровых фильтров очень высоких порядков. Все остальное - грязные извращения. Если вы хотите подрезать частоты, то вы проектируете цифровой фильтр, который это делает, и применяете его к сигналу с помощью БПФ.

Comment: Если пояснять на конкретном примере, то эквалайзер на БПФ сделать вовсе не так просто, как кажется на первый взгляд. Вы можете попробовать просто задать нужную АЧХ симметрично в обе стороны и линейную ФЧХ (это обычно требуется от фильтров), потом сделать обратное преобразование и получить импульсную функцию фильтра, а она окажется комплексной, то есть такой фильтр невозможен и результатом его применения будут специфические искажения. Чтобы делать что-то с помощью БПФ сложнее размывания картинки (свертка с функцией Гаусса), придется подучить теорию цифровой обработки сигналов.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Помните мой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/713044/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)? Кажется, ответ дан верно, не так ли? Мне просто не хватило пояснений, чтобы реализовать описанное самостоятельно. Вы думаете, если я получу ответы на список вопросов, которые я изложил в дополнении к теме, мне удастся получить результат самому? Или мне безнадёжно нужно пройти курс теории?..

Comment: Да, помню. Поэтому я сейчас в ответе и описал, как давил шум 15 лет назад с помощью БПФ. Но нам тогда как раз прочитали курс цифровой обработки сигналов, которой я очень интересовался. Не знаю, что вам сказать. Надо бы вам подучить теорию, хотя бы что касается преобразования Фурье и алгоритма БПФ. Хотя бы поверхностно как-то подучить.

Comment: Я принимаю ваш ответ. А вообще, нет ли готовых реализаций? Просто, теперь я стал более чётко понимать чего хочу, в отличии от прежних моих попыток выяснить это. Библиотеки со спектральным шумоподавлением вроде есть (та же Bass.net), а вот с вычитанием частот, не припомню (причём мягким переходом). В случае удаления частот вроде как параметр берётся шумовой порог. Это так? Что этот шумовой означает, если знаете?

Comment: Такая штука в TeamViewer есть.

Comment: У меня шумовой порог означал модуль в фурье-образе образца шума. То есть sqrt(re[i]²+im[i]²). То есть порогов было много, каждый для своей частоты. Есть такой вариант шумоподавления, когда сигнал с амплитудой ниже treshold просто давится в 0. Когда появляется полезный сигнал, он просто маскирует шум, вычитания которого в такой схеме на самом деле не происходит. На этом же эффекте маскировки, кстати, работает алгоритм MP3.

Comment: Вроде как там (в TeamViewer) шумовой порог задаётся пользователем либо ставится в "авто". А вы говорите о каком то значений, о котором пользователю и дела нет (нет?). Хорошо, а что на счёт реализаций с удалением определённых частот?

Comment: Есть где-то код на C++ того, что описано в ответе, но уж больно обезьяний код. Никому не дам. Не хочу позориться. Кроме того, там БПФ считается целочисленной арифметикой на ассемблере x86. И десяток преобразований с разной длиной. Я его сейчас сам не пойму, если начну читать.

Comment: Есть еще один интересный вариант, который можно попробовать реализовать. Разбить сигнал на полосы по частоте с помощью кроссоверов высокого порядка. И дальше шумовой порог отдельно для каждой полосы. Тут и без Фурье можно обойтись. Но это лишь идея. Не известно, будет ли работать, не запоганит ли сигнал куча кроссоверов. [Википедия.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Фильтр_Линквица_—_Райли)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то гугл много чего находит. Вот, например, нашлась оболочка для шарпа и либы FFTW: https://github.com/tszalay/FFTWSharp

> Ну, говоря об обратном преобразовании, готовых реализаций вообще не нашёл.

Очень боюсь в чем-то наврать, поскольку работал с БПФ очень давно и многое забыл. Там есть несколько вариантов. Прореживание по времени или по частоте, а также нормирование по мощности. Второе связано с незначительными изменениями в операции "бабочка". У меня при прямом преобразовании в "бабочке" присутствовало деление на 2, а при обратном нет. Кроме того, перед обратным преобразованием надо было выполнить комплексное сопряжение над фурье-образом, то есть просто изменить знак мнимых частей.

Задача была - вычитание спектра шума из сигнала в реальном времени. Вообще-то спектры, полученные БПФ, вычитать нельзя, как я уже написал в комментарии к вопросу. Поэтому я на каждом блоке сигнала уже не помню как строил цифровой фильтр, который максимально соответствовал бы производимой операции. Естественно, для каждого блока сигнала такой фильтр получается разный. Поэтому я строил два фильтра: для одного блока и для следующего. Оба их применял а результат уже на сигнале линейно интерполировал. В общем, БПФ прямых и обратных, да еще и с разной длиной блока для этого приходилось делать порядка десяти. Но 10 БПФ все равно быстрее 1 НПФ (непрерывное преобразование Фурье), с которым все проще для данной задачи. Я тогда так и не разобрался на уровне математики, почему это вообще работает, но работало хорошо.

Надеюсь, этот пример вам чем-то поможет. Как минимум, поможет понять, что все не так просто, и БПФ это не волшебная палочка, а лишь способ быстрого вычисления сверток.